# JavaScript library to generate PDF from HTML (Phonegap compatible)

Tags: javascript, cordova, pdf-generation, phonegap-plugins

I am searching for a (client-side) JavaScript library which can generate a PDF file from the current opened HTML page. It should be compatible with Phonegap(iOS AND Android) as well.

I found jsPDF but it doesn't seem to work with Phonegap. Are there alternatives?

Comment: I've cast a close vote on your question for the following reason : Questions asking to **recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow** as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this question, It offers a solution to generate a pdf from HTML in both server side and client side by diffrent library

[Javascript PDF Generator library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20029132/javascript-pdf-generator-library)

[wkhtmltopdf](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) and [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) are good server side solution for your issue